# Fetch data via GS - response code 200 but data always "undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, urlfetch

I try to fetch the data given by https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum

It looks like

> [{"date":"1546560000","totalLiquidityUSD":273845651.27077854},{"date":"1546646400","totalLiquidityUSD":288674544.41292274},{"date":"1546732800","totalLiquidityUSD":297321259.6930144},{"date":"1546819200","totalLiquidityUSD":286168221.103729},{"date":"1546905600","totalLiquidityUSD":285073686.76345384}, ...

when I open it in chrome.

In python with `urllib.request.urlopen()` it works fine.

Here in Google Sheets I try

```js
function myFunction() {
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum").getResponseCode()
  var data2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum").getContentText()
  console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum").getContentText())
}
```

Here data = 200, but data2 = undefined. I think it is a newbie question, but I am unfamiliar with JS or GS.

Thanks for your help!

Best,

Dominik

Comment: how do you access the data? you only showed in your question how you tried to access the response code and the response headers.

Comment: At the moment, I just use the debugger and log data and data2

Comment: Please be more specific. What is undefined? The variable data, or the response data? If the variable data is undefined, how can you know that the response code is 200?

Comment: what exactly are the values of data and data2?

Comment: Ah sorry, 

data = 200
data2 = undefined

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: what does `console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum").getContentText())` gives you ?

Comment: It logs the content of the page.

> Logging output too large. Truncating output. [{"date":"1546560000","totalLiquidityUSD":273845651.27077854}, ...

Comment: isn't it what you want?

Comment: But when I use "var data2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum").getContentText()" I still get an "undefined" and cannot access the data. Do I need to decode it?

Comment: add your full code to your question

Comment: Where to you access the value of `data2`. How is your function called?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Dominik1999/45559b6062d0c4f441417044be7aa4ac

line 80 is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the data as JSON object by parsing the ContentText as JSON, then you can iterate the data with a for or use it in any other way you need.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum").getContentText()
  
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  for(const d of data) {
    console.log("DATE: " + d.date)
    console.log("LIQUIDITY: " + d.totalLiquidityUSD)
  }
}
```

Comment: ```function myFunction() {
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum').then(response => {
    console.log(response.status) // response.status will return the status code
    for (const header of response.headers) {
      console.log(header) // header[0] will return the header key and header[1] will return it's value
    }
    return response.json()
  }).then(json => console.log(json)) // in JSON you will have the array of your JSON objects
}```
returns 

```TypeError: UrlFetchApp.fetch(...).then is not a function```

Comment: This won't work inside a Google App Script

Comment: @thchp never worked with GS, tought it accept JS too..

Comment: ah ok, sorry for the ugly layout. I need the Google App Script for my work

Comment: @Dominik what are you trying to get in your GS the data or the headers?

Comment: @Dominik if you prompt `console.log(data2)` it returns the whole content..

Comment: I need the data. ok now I get it, the data is a string.

Comment: @Dominik i've updated my answer check it out :)